# I can't get my discord bot to send a link

Tags: python, replit

This is the code that I used:

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def music(ctx, *args):
  global mesg
  
    mesg = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/759465899844567157/797828093494558740/videoplayback.mp4'.join(args)
    return await client.say(mesg)
```

Nevermind it's been fixed, I had to restart the bot when I add a new command ‍♂️

Comment: Is this a part of a function or what? If it were like that in the code you would get an error, that `return` is outside function.

Comment: Please may you add more information and clarity on what you want to do?

Comment: I am trying to make a bot I'm working on, send a link/video but I can't seem to get it correct,